# Event receiver, unpublish

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, column, event-handlers

Hi how could i use a event receiver based on a document library, to se if the user has unpublished a dokument in the library, in the mean time also i want to update a field in the document library when the user unpublish the document?

Any kind of help or suggestions...

============================`

## UPDATE

I only want to se if the user has entered unpublish on a document then i want to update a field value, if the document is published do nothing..

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties){
    //was published/approved before
    if(properties.BeforeProperties["ows__ModerationStatus"] == 0){
       //is now unpublished/pending

    }
 }
```

## UPDATE 08:47

When user enter unpublish i want to clear a field but the field does not get updated? in a document library

```
 //was published/approved before
        if (properties.BeforeProperties["ows__ModerationStatus"].ToString() == "0")
        {

            //is now unpublished/pending
            if (properties.AfterProperties["ows__ModerationStatus"].ToString() == "2")
            {
                string mycol_internal = "";

                using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
                {
                    mycol_internal = web.Lists[properties.ListId].Fields["DisplayNameField"].InternalName;
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;


                }
                properties.AfterProperties[mycol_internal] = "";
            }
        }
```

I am using ItemUpdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an event receiver for document library and check on itemupdated or updating event if the publishing state has been changed. You can use the ModerationInformation to see if it is in a published version or not. Approved is published. If you don't have approval, you can go for "Level", where 1 is published and 2 is unpublished.

Example:

```
  public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties){
        //was published before
        if(properties.BeforeProperties["Level"].ToString() == "1"){
           //is now unpublished                    
           if(properties.AfterProperties["Level"].ToString() == "2"){
                //do what you want to do
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Do u have some example?

Comment: i will update....

Comment: I also get  the error, cannot use == operand object,int

Comment: ah sorry you neet to cast to string..i update it

Comment: Alright i will update again in the top

Comment: you don't need to update in the top, people can see my answer :) you just need to verify if my answer is good for you and then select it as an answer or not

Comment: and use properties.web without openweb() and without using. You don't need to dispose the properties.web, sharepoint does that for you.

Comment: alright i have approved pls se my update, should it be __ or _ after ows?

Comment: You need to use __ double line

Comment: Alright i will try it out now i think Itemupdating will not fire...

Comment: how have you registered the event to the document library?

Comment: I have done nothing? only listtemplateid="101" in my elements.xml u mean?

Comment: yes i mean this. now you need to reactivate your feature

Comment: i get object reference not set on if(properties.BeforeProperties["ows__ModerationStatus"] == 0){ when i publish and also when i try to unpublish

Comment: sorry i changed it, try that

Comment: i still get object reference not set on if(properties.BeforeProperties["Level"].ToString() == "1"){

Comment: are you debugging sometimes? try it with internal name: vti_level instead of Level

Comment: yes i debugg its why i said to you the error