# Unpublish document in document library

Tags: document-library, publishing

I only want to update a field when i unpublish the document, right not it fires two times when i publish (changes the value) and when i unpublish also?
how could i solve so the code only runs on Unpublished?

```
   public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdating(properties);

    try
    {
        if (properties.ListItem == null)
            return;

        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;

            properties.AfterProperties["Field"]="Hello";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log it
    }
}
```

My code fire twice when publishing and when unpublishing?

Comment: Please try to move the "base.ItemUpdating(properties)" code to the bottom of the event receiver. Publishing could also mean to checkin and to publish which consits of 2 steps so you're event receiving is fired twice.

Comment: So how should i solve it then?@Andreas

Comment: i have it in the bottom now, still the same.. @Andreas

Comment: Like I also wrote in my first comment I think it's correct that it's executed twice because when you change a document and you checkin, ItemUpdating is executed twice too. Maybe this [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146623/event-receiver-unpublish) helps